# bootstrap tooltip color depending on container

Tags: css, twitter, tooltip

how can I change bootstrap tooltip background-color depending on container

my header is white and my footer is black

```
#header .tooltip-inner{
background-color:fade(@grayWhite,80);
}

#footer .tooltip-inner{
background-color:fade(@black,80);
}
```

it doesn't work 
how can I do that ?

I only can do (for all)

```
.tooltip-inner {
  color: @grayLight;
  background-color:fade(@grayWhite,80);
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 2.x based on the variable names.

Usually you need to be a little more specific with the selectors but if your css is coming before Bootstrap's css, then their classes will over-ride yours. You can try #header > .tooltip > .tooltip-inner or just put !important but make sure your classes are after theirs.